# Where to store uploaded images on server

Tags: java, spring, file, rest, upload

This question might be a duplicate one, but I could not find the exact answer so I am asking it.

I am developing a Spring REST application. I want to take some images in POST request and store them somewhere in the server, which is not in the project directory, so it won't be a of the WAR file.

I will be storing image URLs in the database and sending them in GET response.

How can I do that?
If there is some tutorial link that would be helpful.

Comment: @kirkpatt let me check that link, and if it solves my problem, I will remove the question. Thx :)

Comment: If you want a more specific answer for your situation, you may consider adding more details to your question. There are a lot of questions out there very similar to yours that may or may not solve your issue.

Comment: Great way to start a question...

Comment: Maybe he wants to know how to store files (images etc) not in his hosting storage. But 'some where out there' that he can upload and get the file's URL to show in his website.

Comment: @SulungNugroho that is exactly what I need.

Comment: Try to use CDN where you can upload, store and retrieve your image to your user in your website. How to? Don't worry, you will get an API from them, as well as several guides how to do it. By CDN, your image is can be deliver to the nearest place to your host to improve loading time. Some CDN offer 14 days free trial with 20GB storage. Need payment after this quota reached. Hope it could help.